# Validating Node.Js JWT token in asp.net/Authorize

Tags: asp.net, node.js, jwt

I am in the process of splitting up my asp.net service to multiple micro services. As a process, I have created my identity service using Node.Js and it uses JWT for tokens.

Now i want to use this token in C# so that all my [Authorise] attributes use this token and allow access.

I have looked at many implementations, but could not get this to work. Since JWT is a standard impementation, i do not understand a reason why this would not work.

This is my C# code

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
 {
            var issuer = "myorg/identity2";
            string audienceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["as:AudienceId"];
            byte[] audienceSecret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode
            ("xfecrrt7CV");

            // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },
                    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                    {
                        new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, audienceSecret)
                    }
                });
```

However, I get this error everytime i try to access a protected method.

```
{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}
```

Is there anything i am missing here? How do i add the claim identity to this?

Comment: Are you sure this key `xfecrrt7CV`  is the same that the key used for signing and is base64url encoded?

Comment: Token is passed as bearer token in header correctly. I tested the token on https://jwt.io/, if i dont select "secret base64 encoded" it gets validated correctly. I tried converting it to byte array using UTF8, Unicode encoding.. but it did not work.

Comment: Then the error is here `byte[] audienceSecret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode("xfecrrt7CV");` you are trying to base64url decode a string that is not. Did you try `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xfecrrt7CV");`?

Comment: Yes i did try Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("xfecrrt7CV")

Comment: Is issuer the api endpoint on NodeJS side? Can you show us how you declared the controller for that route? With express you should register a middleware like this: app.use('/myorg/identity2', expressJwt({secret: secret})); so that the request contains the token

Comment: Here is my node code, issuer is not an endpoint. As per my understanding it is used only for comparing the decoded issuer names.

 var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
        var token = jwt.sign({
            "email": user.email,
            "user_id": user._id
           },"xfecrrt7CV" , {
            issuer: "myorg/identity2"});

Comment: maybe `JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions` is checking the audience , but your token have not `aud` claim. Try to remove `AllowedAudiences = new[] { audienceId },`

Comment: Finally it was resolved. One of my friend debugged the Identity source code and recommended to increased the key length. After increasing the key length, i was able to validate the token.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it was resolved. One of my friends debugged the Identity source code and recommended to increased the key length. After increasing the key length, I was able to validate the token

Comment: Post the edited code here and mark it as the correct answer, to help others who could find this post.